# Given the following conditions, how many tickets do you need to win the lottery?

Tags: combinatorics, lotteries

A lottery game consists of scoring $15$ numbers out of $25$. The chance to hit 11 points with a single ticket in this lottery game is $\frac{1}{11}$. What is the minimum amount of tickets to score $11$ points? And how to choose these tickets?

To win the main prize with one ticket: 
${25 \choose 15} = \frac{25!}{15!(25−15)!} = 3268760$

Probability of hitting 11 numbers with one ticket:

$$\frac{{15 \choose 11} \cdot {10 \choose 4}}{{25 \choose 15}}$$

$$=\frac{\frac{15!}{11!(15−11)!} \cdot \frac{10!}{4!(10−4)!} }{\frac{25!}{15!(25−15)!}}$$

$$=\frac{1365 \cdot 210}{ 3268760}$$

$$=\frac{286650}{3268760}$$

$$\frac{1}{ 11.4033141462 \cdots}$$

$$\approx \frac{1}{11}$$

So the chance to hit $11$ points with a single ticket in this lottery game is $\frac{1}{11}$.

I think that the minimum amount of tickets to score $11$ points is $11$, because $\frac{1}{11} \cdot 11 = 1$ but I am not sure. And I dont know how to choose these tickets.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific and show work. What does it mean to score 15 numbers out of 25?

Comment: The game has 25 numbers (1 to 25) and you can choose 15 numbers of those 25.

Comment: Are you asking, "What is the minimum number of tickets one must buy in order to guarantee scoring at least one point on at least one ticket?"

Comment: What is the minimum number of tickets one must buy in order to guarantee scoring at least 11 points on at least one ticket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let’s solve an easier problem. There are $25$ total numbers, $15$ of them are winning, and we still want at least $11$ points, but this time the lottery tickets are only $11$ numbers long. In order to buy enough tickets to be guaranteed $11$ points on one of them, in the worst case scenario ${25\choose 11}-{15\choose 11}=4456035$ of the tickets would be duds.

What would happen if the tickets were actually $15$ numbers long instead of $11$? Well then this would make things easier because instead of having to test $4456035$ combinations of $11$ numbers individually, we can now test ${15\choose 11}=1365$ of them at once!

This means we now only have to fail at most $4456035/1365=3264.49$ times. So we need to buy $3265$ tickets with the following strategy. For the first $3264$ tickets, ensure that no two tickets have the same combination of $11$ numbers. For the last ticket, make sure that it includes as many combinations of $11$ numbers as possible that haven’t already appeared in the other tickets.